# How to take 8 different rows from the table mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table consists of two columns and a lot of rows

```
   | id | type      |
   |----------------|
   |  1 | sweater   |
   |  2 | jeans     |
   |  3 | pants     |    
   |  4 | trousers  |
   |  5 | T-shirt   |
   |  6 | socks     |
   |  7 | polo      |
   |  8 | shirt     |
   |  9 | sweater   |
   | 10 | jeans     |  
   | 11 | T-shirt   |
   ..................
    and so oooon.......
```

I need to take 8 different rows from the table where the types are : hat, scarf, earrings, necklace, ring, purse, gloves and belt

I have never needed such a query, I had tried to think out smth.

```
    SELECT src, 
    type 
    FROM accs_w
    WHERE TYPE =  'hat'
    OR TYPE =  'earnings'
    OR TYPE =  'purse'
    OR TYPE =  'scarf'
    OR TYPE =  'necklace'
    OR TYPE =  'ring'
    OR TYPE =  'belt'
    OR TYPE =  'gloves'
    LIMIT 8
```

but, ofcourse it didn't return me anything

I will appreciate your answer, thank you!

Comment: If your query doesn't return anything, then perhaps those values are not in the table.

Comment: smells like a very non-normalized database...

Comment: @Gordon Linoff I meant: the wrong data

Comment: @ SnakeDoc that's just an example, never mind)

Comment: What does the `src` column looks like?

Comment: @Everton Agner ... smth. like this : //pi3.lmcdn.ru/img172x248/M/O/MO002HWKU687_1.jpg

Comment: @CostaRassco I strongly advise you to reformulate your question. Explain us a little bit better what do you have and what do you need.

Comment: @Everton Agner couldn't you explain why are asking? you have already solve my problem with the answer below) is it smth wrong?

Comment: Oh, if it's solved then it's okay. I thought you were still looking for the solution.

Comment: @Everton Agner can I ask you: but how can I take the items randomly? the query always returns the same data...but if I need the random one, how can I do that? thank you in advance!

Comment: You could try something similar to this (I don't know if it works, since I don't have MySQL here): `SELECT FROM accs_W WHERE type in ('hat', 'earnings', 'purse', 'scarf', 'necklace', 'ring', 'belt', 'gloves') GROUP BY type, id, src HAVING id = FLOOR(MAX(id) * RAND())` - Reference from http://akinas.com/pages/en/blog/mysql_random_row

Comment: @Everton Agner, no, sorry, that doesn't help! I'll think out smth thank you))

Comment: See my answer. I think that works for returning random rows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using an `IN()` Clause:

```
SELECT src, type FROM accs_w WHERE TYPE IN (
   'hat', 'earnings', 'purse', 'scarf', 'necklace', 'ring', 'belt', 'gloves'
)
```

You don't need to `LIMIT` the output, since you know you'll get only the 8 rows (in this specific case).

EDIT:

It seems that what the OP needs is to get a random `SRC` for each `TYPE` defined in his subset. Here is how it could be done.

[Full SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d1139/30)

```
select a.type, (
    select b.src
    from accs_w b
    where b.type = a.type
    order by rand()
    limit 1
)
from (
  select 'T-shirt' as type union all
  select 'jeans' as type union all
  select 'pants' as type
) as a;
```

It's not pretty and - I think - not performatic, but it get's the job done.

Comment: If the original query returns no rows, I fail to see how using an `in` would magically cause rows to be returned.

Comment: @Everton Agner thank you, but I will need to use LIMIT, there a lot of other items

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have to admit I've overlooked this question. The OP needs to clarify what he wants.

Comment: Hopefully now I understood what the OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a query that gives you randomly one row for each type. It assumes that the range of the id value is < 1 million. If not, increase the 1000000 to something bigger.

```
create table accs_w
(
   id integer,
   type varchar(20)
);

insert into accs_w values (1,'sweater');
insert into accs_w values (2,'jeans');
insert into accs_w values (3,'pants');

insert into accs_w values (4,'sweater');
insert into accs_w values (5,'jeans');
insert into accs_w values (6,'pants');

select * from accs_w a
where id in
(
  select x mod 1000000 from
  ( select type, max( floor(rand()*1000000) *1000000 + id) x from accs_w 
     group by type
  ) b
);
```

I am assuming you want to sample one row of each type and you don't care which row you get as long as you get one of each type.